# How to inflate a layout on list item click according to list item (Listview is populated via database)?

Tags: android, listview, android-database

I am trying to build ad posting app. I have made a listview inflated it from database and i want to inflate a layout on its click. But layout is not getting any data.

Listview code:

```
public class List1 extends Activity{

    ImageView img1;
    TextView txt,price1;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    UserDbHelper userDbHelper;
    byte[] photo;

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list1);

          userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
          sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
          price1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Price);
          TextView des=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.des);

          ImageView img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
          Intent in=getIntent();
          int intValue = in.getIntExtra("id",0);
          String i=Integer.toString(intValue);

          Cursor cursor=userDbHelper.getContact(i,sqLiteDatabase);
          if(cursor.moveToFirst())
          {
              String NAME=cursor.getString(0);
              String PHONE=cursor.getString(1);
              String PRICE=cursor.getString(2);
              String DESC=cursor.getString(3);
              byte[] PHOTO=cursor.getBlob(4);
              Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
              img1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
              price1.setText(PRICE);
              des.setText(DESC);
          }
    }
}
```

[This is listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOW4K.jpg)     
[This is showing after listview item click and i want it to be inflated with the data of list item which is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdQLs.jpg)

Comment: Please describe more for solution or post some code in which you getting problem

Comment: I am getting no error in this  ..and i have attached image above in form of a link. Please have a look.

Comment: please refer this http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90

Comment: App is getting stopped when i tried  `String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);` i think because i have 1 image view and 3 textview in listview
`

Comment: please post your error log here. so i can help out you

Comment: `08-07 10:00:24.018 27592-27592/vanisha.first.com.vrad E/DATABASE OPERATIONS: DATABASE CREATE OR OPEN
08-07 10:00:24.098 27592-27592/vanisha.first.com.vrad I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42d19f50 time:1876641` tht is wht i am geetting when i click on listview item

Comment: Please post whole log on your question so i can help out